# Is it possible to embed a thumbnail in a .mkv file?

Tags: ffmpeg, linux, mkv, thumbnails, embedding

I am trying to embed a thumbnail in a `.mkv` file with `h265` video encoding using `ffmpeg` from the Linux command line. I am able to embed thumbnails in `h264`-encoded `.mp4` files using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i video-in.mp4 -i thumb.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

However, a similar command substituting `.mkv` files does not correctly embed the thumbnail:

```
ffmpeg -i video-in.mkv -i thumb.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mkv
```

`ffmpeg` will run just fine, throwing no warnings or errors, but the thumbnail that shows in Dolphin after it's run its course is a generic auto-generated thumbnail instead of the one I specified with `-i thumb.png`.

I first learned how to do this while reading the `ffmpeg` documentation [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) (a bit further down, where it explains dispositions). I noticed that it says "Not all muxers support embedded thumbnails, and those who do, only support a few formats, like JPEG or PNG." This makes me think that maybe the matroska/mkv muxer simply doesn't support embedded thumbnails. However, further research has me confused.

The [ffmpeg Formats documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) doesn't list thumbnail(s) as an option in the metadata section of [the matroska muxer docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#matroska), which further supports the theory that embedding is impossible. I figured I'd double-check that thumbnails are listed as an option for mp4s just to be sure. However, the [mov/mp4/ismv muxer section](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#mov_002c-mp4_002c-ismv) doesn't even *have* a Metadata sub-section.

The [MP4 File Format Documentation](https://docs.fileformat.com/video/mp4/) I've been able to find isn't very helpful. I can't tell whether thumbnail embedding is possible based on this documentation alone (though obviously I know from experience that it's possible).

The [MKV Container Documentation](https://docs.fileformat.com/video/mkv/) is a lot more thorough, though, and it says in the first section [("What is an MKV File?")](https://docs.fileformat.com/video/mkv/#what-is-an-mkv-file) that "MKV also supports descriptions, ratings, ***cover art***, and even chapter points" (emphasis mine). In the ["Matroska Structure"](https://docs.fileformat.com/video/mkv/#matroska-structure) section it also lists "Attachments" as one of the top-level elements of the container structure. All of this leads me to believe that embedded thumbnails *are in fact* possible with .mkv files.

So, to summarize: on the one hand, `ffmpeg`'s documentation makes me think I can't embed thumbnails in `.mkv` files. But the MKV file format documentation makes me think I *should* be able to. I haven't been able to figure out for sure either way, though, and even if it is possible, the method for doing so differs from the method I use for `.mp4` files.

Is it possible to embed thumbnails in `.mkv` files? If so, how would I do it (preferably using `ffmpeg` on Linux)?

Answer (score 2):

I was also going down this rabbit hole and found that there's an option `-attach filename` that's more specific to `mkv` files. It's at the end of the "Main Options" section of the manual: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -attach cover.jpg -metadata:s:t:0 mimetype=image/jpeg -c copy out.mkv
```

The `-metadata:s:t:0` specifically selects the first attachment stream (which should be just the cover photo).

Comment: This works but I still would like to remind that **the thumbnail image must have "cover" as its file name**, such as "cover.jpg" or "cover.png". If we use file names like "thumb.png", FFmpeg won't report an error, but the thumbnail also won't display properly on the MKV output.